# Multi variable linear differential equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the general solution to the following first order linear differential equation.

$y′  =  \frac{xy}{(x^2 + 11)^2} $

I got the solution $y  =  C(x^2 + 11)^{1/2}$ but this is incorrect. I don't know how I could be wrong. What is the right answer and can someone explain the method that they used to get to this answer? Maybe then I can see where i went wrong. I used Integration to solve this question.

Comment: Divide by $y$ both sides and integrate.

Answer (score 1):

$$y′=\frac { xy }{ (x^{ 2 }+11)^{ 2 } } \\ \int { \frac { dy }{ y }  } =\int { \frac { xdx }{ (x^{ 2 }+11)^{ 2 } }  } \\ \int { \frac { dy }{ y }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \frac { d\left( { x }^{ 2 }+11 \right)  }{ (x^{ 2 }+11)^{ 2 } }  } \\ \ln { y=-\frac { 1 }{ 2\left( x^{ 2 }+11 \right)  }  } +C\\ \\ y=C{ e }^{ -\frac { 1 }{ 2\left( x^{ 2 }+11 \right)  }  }\\ $$

Comment: Your exponent contains an extra $-$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [separable ODE](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx). Thus, you can separate it by dividing both sides by $y$:
$$\frac{1}{y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{(x^2+11)^2}$$
Now, integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives:
$$\int \frac{1}{y}~dy=\int \frac{x}{(x^2+11)^2}~dx$$
To integrate the left hand side is straightforward. To integrate the right hand side, you can use the substitution:
$$u=x^2+11$$
$$du=2x~dx$$
To obtain:
$$\int \frac{x}{(x^2+11)^2}~dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u^2}~du$$
Can you continue?